# Return values mess up when looped

Tags: java

So I'm pretty new to java and I have to make an exercise for school in BlueJ. It has to be a system for a boat hiring service, one of the outputs has to be the total time that all the boats are hired that day (all boats only get hired once per day). For this method I'm using two classes, hiredBoat and summary. My input for the start and end time is in format hhmm(int), I put the object hiredBoat inside an array:

```
private ArrayList<hiredBoat> hiredboats;


public void addHired(int boatnumber, int starttime, int endtime, int usedfuel, boolean damage)
{
   hiredeBoat boat = new hiredBoat(boatnumber, start, end, usedfuel, damage);
    hiredBoats.add(boat);
    boatamount++;
}
```

In hiredBoat I have two methods to return the amount of hours hired and minutes hired. The getHour() method works like this, the getMin() is exact the same except for the actual return int:

```
public int getHour()
{
   endtimehour = endtime / 100;
   endtimemin = endtime % 100;
   if(endtimemin >= 60)
   {
       endtimehour++;
       endtimemin = endtimemin - 60;
   }

   starttimehour = starttime / 100;
   starttimemin = starttime % 100;
   if(starttimemin >= 60)
   {
       starttimehour++;
       starttimemin = starttimemin - 60;
   }

   totalhour = endtimehour - starttimehour ;
   totalmin = endtimemin - starttimemin;

   if(totaalmin < 0)
   {
       totalhour--;
       totalmin = 60 + totalmin;
   }

   return totalhour;
}
```

The getHour and getMin methods work as they should when I create a hiredBoat object.

My method to get the total time of all boat being hired is in my summary object:

```
public void getTotaltimehired()
{
    totalhours = 0;
    totalminutes = 0;
    for(hiredBoat hiredBoat : hiredboats)
    {
        totalhours = totalhours + hiredBoat.getHour();
        totalminutes = totalminutes + hiredBoat.getMin();
    }

    if(totalminutes >= 60)
    {
        extrahours = totalminutes / 60;
        totalminutes = totalminutes % 60;
        totalhours = totalhours + extrahours;
    }

    System.out.println("Total time hired: " + totalhours + " uur en " + totalminutes + " minuten");
}
```

The big problem that I have is that when I create a hiredBoat the getHour() and getMin() work fine, but when I loop to add the all up it doesn't

Comment: Hint: read about java naming conventions. Class names start UpperCase; always.

Comment: Beyond that: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Recude your problem to the absolute minimum that can be compiled and executed; and give that here. As "but when I loop to add the all up it doesn't" isnt a description we could help with!

Answer (score 0):

> when I loop to add the all up it doesn't [work]

You should probably move that if statement inside the loop.

```
int totalhours = 0;
int totalminutes = 0;

for(HiredBoat boat : hiredboats)
{
    totalhours += boat.getHour();
    totalminutes += boat.getMin();

    if(totalminutes >= 60)
    {
        int extrahours = totalminutes / 60;
        totalminutes = totalminutes % 60;
        totalhours += extrahours;
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand your logic enough to see why that doesn't sum the values correctly, though.

Comment: Your last paragraph is why decided to not answer this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you never declare variables in methods; that means that you you probably use fields, which are shared between all methods of a class.

Try declaring any variable that can in the method.